# How to set relative path for a hyperlink in Excel through Java/groovy

Tags: java, excel, groovy, hyperlink

I have a directory there I have one Excel file and one text file. I want to set a hyperlink in my Excel for that text file with relative path. Wherever I can store that directory in my system and that hyperlink should work.

Problem: If I am setting absolute path for the text file in the hyperlink then it creates problem when I change the directory location.

So I want to set a relative path for the hyperlink so wherever I store my directory the hyperlink should work because my both files are stored inside one parent directory.

Comment: Retrieve the path for Excel file and append it with text file name and use it in Hyperlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the solution `String relativePath = "../parentdir/fileToLink.txt";`

If this path get set there then its working fine.